# Start application into specific workspace (desktop)

Tags: raspbian, script, desktop

I've set up my Raspbian with 4 workspaces/desktops and like to start an application via script into one specific desktop. Is there a parameter I can add to my script

```
#!/bin/bash
#
myApp &
```

to send myApp to desktop no. x?
Thx and regards,
Bernd

Comment: Not sure if this works on a Pi (none of mine have screens on them let alone two at the moment) but there is a Debian program call wmctrl https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl that lets you select the window `wmctrl -a x` that may do what you need.

Comment: wmctrl works on my Pi. Of course had to install it first. Thx!

Comment: No problems - glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: switch to desired workspace, then launch the program in it.
`xdotool` can do this. It's a x session manipulation utility.
Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507094/369481

Install with this command:

```
sudo apt install -y xdotool
```

To switch to a certain desktop, use this command:

```
xdotool set_desktop 1
```

Note: in xdotool, desktops begin at `0`, while the window manager treats the first desktop as "Desktop 1".

Example script:

```
xdotool set_desktop 1
chromium-browser example.com &
xdotool set_desktop 0
```

Method 2: launch the program on current desktop, then move it to the desired desktop.
Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/31242
`wmctrl` can do this.
Example script:

```
chromium-browser example.com &
wmctrl -r "Chromium" -t 1
```